# MySQL transfer ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, character-set

How to transfer data from Database with latin1 character set, to database UTF-8. And on transferring convert data from latin1 to UTF-8 e.g., û->ū, ë->ė, þ->ž, á->į and etc.

Comment: Hope this [link](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/TIP_Convert_latin1_to_UTF-8_in_MySQL) will help you

Comment: Ok, i managed to output all data from latin1 database to file, using `C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\mysql\bin>mysqldump -uroot -p --default-charact
er-set=latin1 9001_komeksimas pg_zodynas > c:\qqq.sql`. Now the file is in ASCII encoding, but it has all the alphabet I need. So how to make a transfer to other db?

Comment: You can use GUI client such as (Yog, Toad or smth else). Or you can run `mysql -uroot -p < log_file.sql` (dont forget to convert file to utf8)

Comment: After transferring, the data remains with old wrong characters... Any more ideas? I dump file as mentioned above and then this is what i tried:
1)open dump with notepad++ change encoding to utf and run your query - same characters as before it was dumped.
2)just run your query without changing encoding. the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. As I looked more into my first DB it had UTF-8 encoding, but all fields in tables was latin1. And data in there was windows-1257. So the solution:

`SELECT CONVERT(CAST(pavad as BINARY) USING cp1257) pg_zodynas`